# How to call generic property from another generic method

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

Here is my generic method from which i want to return the class object

```
 public class TestBase
{
    public T NavigateandReturntheObject<T>() where T : new()
    {
        //do navigate to page stuff and return the page object

        //previously it was - return new T();

        //Now i want to do something like this
        return PageObjectBase<T>.PageObject;
    }
}
```

Above method calling the below static generic class which will handle object creation of a particular class

```
 public static class PageObjectBase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T singleTonObject;
    public static T PageObject
    {
        get
        {
            return InstanceCreation();
        }
    }

    public static T InstanceCreation()
    {
        if (singleTonObject == null)
        {
            singleTonObject = new T();
        }

        return singleTonObject;
    }

}
```

How can i call the PageObject property from my test base class please advice.
Note : I have searched forum and find answers relevant to generic method to another generic method calling.The same is achieved by reflection.Can we use reflection in my case too? If so how can we do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another constraint 'class' to NavigateandReturntheObject

```
public T NavigateandReturntheObject<T>() where T : class,new()
```

Complete Code.

```
public class TestBase
{
    public T NavigateandReturntheObject<T>() where T : class,new()
    {
        //do navigate to page stuff and return the page object

        //previously it was - return new T();

        //Now i want to do something like this
        return PageObjectBase<T>.PageObject;
    }
}
```

Demo Code

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public TestClass()
    {
        Name = "Dummy Name";
    }
}

var testBase = new TestBase();
var sample = testBase.NavigateandReturntheObject<TestClass>();
Console.WriteLine(sample.Name);
```

Output

```
Dummy Name
```

Comment: The contraint `class` would not be able to able to achieve what the OP wants. Although adding a new contrain is the way to go. Check my comment where I describe the contrain needed.

Comment: @bradbury9 am curious on why above won't work. I have added sample client code now, with output. Why do you think above wont work ?

Comment: This works .I didn't know this is as simple as that.So the problem is that the constraint in both the places(calling method and the method it calls) should be same.Thanks to both of you for looking into this